# Does .NET MAUI support ListView in VS2019 v16.11.0 Preview 3.0?

Tags: android, xamarin, maui

I am trying to convert a Xamarin.Forms ListView to .NET MAUI, but it's not working.

I don't seem to be able to find any samples on .NET MAUI ListView at this point.

Comment: CollectionView was introduced ~2 years ago as a replacement for ListView

Comment: I tried with CollectionView, and got the same error.

Why are there no MAUI ListView samples?  I suspect it's not supported yet.

My Xamarin ListView still works today.  ListView is in MAUI.

namespace Microsoft.Maui.Controls
{
    public class ListView : ...

Comment: "same error" - you didn't actually post any error messages.  I had assumed that ListView would not be supported in MAUI at all but apparently I'm wrong

Comment: You have a good point about posting the error, but in this case, I wanted to solve the problem by looking at a sample (if confirmed it existed at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from a few details .NET MAUI will support everything Xamarin.Forms has, at least as a starting point. That includes the `ListView` as you can see it is available in the source [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Controls/src/Core/ListView.cs).

However, it is recommended to use `CollectionView` which is the spiritual successor of the `ListView` with better performance and more functionality.

As for samples on .NET MAUI `ListView`; just use the samples for Xamarin.Forms `ListView` as the syntax will be exactly the same except for maybe a couple of renamed properties.

Comment: Your ListView example worked for me.  My issue was with VS 2022 v17 Preview.  Resolved now. Thanks!